# How to combine dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have 2 data frames(`final_combine_df` & `acs_df`) that have a shared column ('CBG'). Dataframe `acs_df` has 2 additional columns that I want to add to the combined dataframe (`acs_total_persons` & `cs_total_building_units`) . For the 'CBG' column values in `acs_df` that match those in `final_combine_df`, I want to add the `acs_total_persons` & `acs_total_housing_units` values to that row.

```
acs_df.head() 
CBG         acs_total_persons   acs_total_housing_units     
10010211001 1925.0              1013.0 1    
10030114011 2668.0              1303.0 2    
10070100043 930.0               532.0 3 
10139534001 1570.0              763.0 4 
10150021023 1059.0              379.0
```

I tried `combine_acs_merge = pd.concat([final_combine,acs_df], sort=True)` but it did not seem to match them up. I also tried `combine_acs_merge = final_combine.merge(acs_df, on='CBG')` and got

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If
>   you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

What do I need to do here?
**Note:** Column `acs_df['CBG']` is type `numpy.float64`, not a string but it should still return. Oddly, when I run the following: `print(acs_df.loc[acs_df['CBG'] == '01030114011'])` it returns an empty dataframe. I created the `acs_df` from a csv file (see below). Is that creating a problem?

```
acs_df = pd.read_csv(acs_data)
```

Comment: Why don't you convert the data types of two columns to one suitable type.

Comment: Make both of them strings or both of them integers. Then run your merge. Because Pandas automatically parses integers from CSV, also make sure that the data frame where `df.CBG.dtype != int` doesn't have non-integers in it. `pd.to_numeric` is your friend.